# Does Locks make guarantees about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted access? example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, synchronized

I learn java Lock.

I have read differences between Lock and Synchronized. And I have misunderstandings with one point of this list.

> A synchronized block makes no guarantees about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted access.

Can you show example exposed this quote?

Locks  makes guarantees about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted access?

### Test for synchronized:

```
package concurrency;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LockVsSync {
    public static int THREAD_NUMBER = 10;
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i=0;i<THREAD_NUMBER;i++){
            threads.add(new MyThread());
        }
        for(Thread thread:threads){
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }
    public static synchronized void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+" int test method begin");
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+" int test method end");
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread with id="+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" executes before test!");
            try {
                test();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("Thread with id="+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" executes after test!");

        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
Thread with id=9 executes before test!
9 int test method begin
Thread with id=10 executes before test!
Thread with id=11 executes before test!
Thread with id=12 executes before test!
Thread with id=13 executes before test!
9 int test method end
Thread with id=9 executes after test!
13 int test method begin
Thread with id=14 executes before test!
Thread with id=15 executes before test!
Thread with id=16 executes before test!
Thread with id=17 executes before test!
13 int test method end
Thread with id=13 executes after test!
12 int test method begin
Thread with id=18 executes before test!
12 int test method end
Thread with id=12 executes after test!
11 int test method begin
11 int test method end
Thread with id=11 executes after test!
10 int test method begin
10 int test method end
Thread with id=10 executes after test!
18 int test method begin
18 int test method end
Thread with id=18 executes after test!
17 int test method begin
17 int test method end
Thread with id=17 executes after test!
16 int test method begin
16 int test method end
Thread with id=16 executes after test!
15 int test method begin
15 int test method end
Thread with id=15 executes after test!
14 int test method begin
14 int test method end
Thread with id=14 executes after test!
```

Thus

```
9 int test method begin
13 int test method begin
12 int test method begin
11 int test method begin
10 int test method begin
18 int test method begin
17 int test method begin
16 int test method begin
15 int test method begin
14 int test method begin
```

the order is not specified.

### Test for Lock

```
public class LockVsSync {
    public static int THREAD_NUMBER = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; i++) {
            threads.add(new MyThread());
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }   

    public static synchronized void test(Lock lock) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " int test method begin");
            Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " int test method end");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread with id=" + Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " executes before test!");
            try {
                test(lock);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
            System.out.println("Thread with id="+ Thread.currentThread().getId() + " executes after test!");

        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
 Thread with id=9 executes before test!
9 int test method begin
Thread with id=10 executes before test!
Thread with id=11 executes before test!
Thread with id=12 executes before test!
Thread with id=13 executes before test!
9 int test method end
13 int test method begin
Thread with id=9 executes after test!
Thread with id=14 executes before test!
Thread with id=15 executes before test!
Thread with id=16 executes before test!
Thread with id=17 executes before test!
13 int test method end
Thread with id=13 executes after test!
12 int test method begin
Thread with id=18 executes before test!
12 int test method end
Thread with id=12 executes after test!
11 int test method begin
11 int test method end
Thread with id=11 executes after test!
10 int test method begin
10 int test method end
Thread with id=10 executes after test!
18 int test method begin
18 int test method end
Thread with id=18 executes after test!
17 int test method begin
17 int test method end
Thread with id=17 executes after test!
16 int test method begin
16 int test method end
Thread with id=16 executes after test!
15 int test method begin
15 int test method end
Thread with id=15 executes after test!
14 int test method begin
14 int test method end
Thread with id=14 executes after test!
```

thus:

```
9 int test method begin
13 int test method begin
12 int test method begin
10 int test method begin
18 int test method begin
17 int test method begin
16 int test method begin
15 int test method begin
14 int test method begin
```

not specified order too.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Indeed they don't, and that applies to intrinsic locks and `Lock` objects alike.

Comment: Since "sequential" is the opposite of "concurrent", clearly multithreading is not there to do sequential work. Need sequential? Use one thread.

Comment: Is it possible to show it an simple example?

Comment: Nondeterministic behavior is notoriously difficult to reliably demonstrate.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I think although Thread.sleep makes not guarantees but usually it can help in simple example.

Comment: Perhaps you already have an idea how to demonstrate it? You have written such code already? That would be a good starting point for your question.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have problems

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Is my test valid for synchronized?

Comment: Looks OK as far as I saw. Just note that the order is not *random*, it's just not specified. Random order would actually be a stronger guarantee.

Comment: You can try with `new ReentrantLock(true)`. Even though *fairness* is overall no strong guarantee, it will probably make your toy example show ordered lock acquisition.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik it is not help me

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have updated code and result

Comment: What do you mean it didn't help you? Did you actually *expect* ordered lock acquisition, and plan to rely on it? That's against the core idea of locks. If you want some tasks executed sequentially, then start rethinking your solution.

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik I just forgot remove **synchronized** from method test(

Comment: If you look inside the HotSpot code the monitor set of waiting threads is implemented as a queue, so there's ordering there. But it is not guaranteed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

test output not specified values because of test method marked as synchronized

### Right variant

```
public class LockVsSync {
    public static int THREAD_NUMBER = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; i++) {
            threads.add(new MyThread());
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }   

    public static  void test(Lock lock) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " int test method begin");
            Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " int test method end");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread with id=" + Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " executes before test!");
            try {
                test(lock);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
            System.out.println("Thread with id="+ Thread.currentThread().getId() + " executes after test!");

        }
    }

}
```

### examlpe of output:

```
Thread with id=9 executes before test!
9 int test method begin
Thread with id=10 executes before test!
Thread with id=11 executes before test!
Thread with id=12 executes before test!
Thread with id=13 executes before test!
9 int test method end
Thread with id=9 executes after test!
10 int test method begin
Thread with id=14 executes before test!
Thread with id=15 executes before test!
Thread with id=16 executes before test!
Thread with id=17 executes before test!
10 int test method end
11 int test method begin
Thread with id=10 executes after test!
Thread with id=18 executes before test!
11 int test method end
Thread with id=11 executes after test!
12 int test method begin
12 int test method end
Thread with id=12 executes after test!
13 int test method begin
13 int test method end
Thread with id=13 executes after test!
14 int test method begin
14 int test method end
Thread with id=14 executes after test!
15 int test method begin
15 int test method end
Thread with id=15 executes after test!
16 int test method begin
16 int test method end
Thread with id=16 executes after test!
17 int test method begin
17 int test method end
Thread with id=17 executes after test!
18 int test method begin
18 int test method end
Thread with id=18 executes after test!
```

Thus `Locks makes guarantees about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted a access` is truth.

Comment: A single example doesn't prove anything. The implementation could have a bug. The question is about the specification.

Comment: You should to approve that implemetntation have a bug

Comment: @EJP **A single example doesn't prove anything** But only 1 example can refute all!!! Can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package lock;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    /**
     * This example shows that Lock maintains ordering
     * in which threads entering the critical section are entered.
     * as opposed to synchronized block
     * 
     * @author Gaurav.Seth
     *
     */
    public class ReentrantLockExample {

        static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        static List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Test using Lock
        public static void testLock(String threadName){
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("Starting:" + threadName);
            l.add("a:" + threadName);
            l.add("b: " + threadName);
            System.out.println(l);
            System.out.println("Ending:" + threadName);
            lock.unlock();
        }

        // Test using synchronized block
        public static void testSynchronized(String threadName){
            synchronized(l){
                System.out.println("Starting:" + threadName);
                l.add("a:" + threadName);
                l.add("b: " + threadName);
                System.out.println(l);
                System.out.println("Ending:" + threadName);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
                t.start();
            }
        }

        static class MyThread implements Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //testLock(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                testSynchronized(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Lock (java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock) does guarantee the lock gaining order.
I see two issues with the code in the question. That is why it is not demonstrating the expected results.

1. The "same" lock object should be used to lock the threads. In the code, it creates new Lock object for each Thread, use that object to take the lock.
2. The threads will not invoke the "lock.lock()" line in the same order they invoke the "System.out.println(...." executes before test!")" line. Thread-1 may execute the "println" line and wait a while, And Thread-2 may execute both "println" line and the "lock.lock()" line. So even though you see, "Thread-1...", "Thread-2...." in the console, The actual order those threads try to acquire the lock is, "Thread-2", "Thread-1".

Below is a code to demonstrate the Thread lock behavior

```
public class App {

public static final int THREAD_COUNT = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    for(int i=1; i<=THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        Thread t = new MyThread(lock);
        t.setName("Thread-" + i);
        t.start();

        /*
         * give some time to thread "t" to go and lock itself before sending the next thread.
         * So that threads will be lock in the order of - Thread-1, Thread-2, ...... Thread-19, Thread-20
         */
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    }
}

static class MyThread extends Thread {

    private final Lock lock;

    public MyThread(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " try to pick the lock");
            lock.lock();
            /* *********************************************************************
             * Locked threads will be released based on the order they got locked
             ********************************************************************** */
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " got the lock");

            /* **************************************************************************
             * sleep/wait this thread enough time,
             * so that other threads can come and lock themselves at "lock.lock()" line
             ************************************************************************** */
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " released the lock");
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

}

- The *Thread.currentThread().sleep(100)* in the *main* method is used to give  the thread "t" enough time to execute both "*println*" line and the "*lock.lock()*" line. So that we see the correct thread locked order in the console
- The *Thread.sleep(2000)* in *MyThread: run* method is used to give enough time for all other threads to come and lock themselves at the "*lock.lock()*" line. (*Even though this delay applies to all the threads, this is necessary for only the first thread*)

Below is the console output of this code (I ran the code and checked the output several times. The results are similar)

```
Thread-1 try to pick the lock
                Thread-1 got the lock
Thread-2 try to pick the lock
Thread-3 try to pick the lock
Thread-4 try to pick the lock
Thread-5 try to pick the lock
Thread-6 try to pick the lock
Thread-7 try to pick the lock
Thread-8 try to pick the lock
Thread-9 try to pick the lock
Thread-10 try to pick the lock
Thread-11 try to pick the lock
Thread-12 try to pick the lock
Thread-13 try to pick the lock
Thread-14 try to pick the lock
Thread-15 try to pick the lock
Thread-16 try to pick the lock
Thread-17 try to pick the lock
Thread-18 try to pick the lock
Thread-19 try to pick the lock
                            Thread-1 released the lock
                Thread-2 got the lock
Thread-20 try to pick the lock
                            Thread-2 released the lock
                Thread-3 got the lock
                            Thread-3 released the lock
                Thread-4 got the lock
                            Thread-4 released the lock
                Thread-5 got the lock
                            Thread-5 released the lock
                Thread-6 got the lock
                            Thread-6 released the lock
                Thread-7 got the lock
                            Thread-7 released the lock
                Thread-8 got the lock
                            Thread-8 released the lock
                Thread-9 got the lock
                            Thread-9 released the lock
                Thread-10 got the lock
                            Thread-10 released the lock
                Thread-11 got the lock
                            Thread-11 released the lock
                Thread-12 got the lock
                            Thread-12 released the lock
                Thread-13 got the lock
                            Thread-13 released the lock
                Thread-14 got the lock
                            Thread-14 released the lock
                Thread-15 got the lock
                            Thread-15 released the lock
                Thread-16 got the lock
                            Thread-16 released the lock
                Thread-17 got the lock
                            Thread-17 released the lock
                Thread-18 got the lock
                            Thread-18 released the lock
                Thread-19 got the lock
                            Thread-19 released the lock
                Thread-20 got the lock
                            Thread-20 released the lock
```

Note: I found this question while looking for some thread related details. Even though this is an old question, Thought to leave this answer for future developers.

Answer (score -3):

> Locks makes guarantees about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted a access?

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> A Lock class can also provide behavior and semantics that is quite different from that of the implicit monitor lock, such as guaranteed ordering, non-reentrant usage, or deadlock detection. If an implementation provides such specialized semantics then the implementation must document those semantics.

There is no such documentation in any of the three `Lock` implementation classes in the JDK. There is nothing stronger than 'fair ordering', as an option.

> What I do wrong?

You didn't do anything wrong. You posted some output that showed no particular order. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Present evidence, please

Comment: @gstackoverflow Request denied. It isn't up to me to prove that there is no such guarantee in the documentation. I would have to quote it all to accomplish that. It is for those who assert it does provide such a guarantee to substantiate their claim. One counter-example would be sufficient. I note that nobody has actually provided one.

Comment: you can provide this counter-example! example when this rule is not performed

Comment: @gstackoverflow That assertion is epistemologically unsound. It could be impossible to prove with a piece of code, as all existing implementations could implement sequencing even though the specification doesn't guarantee it. Or it could be arbitrarily difficult to show. The only material fact is that the specification doesn't guarantee it.